# Plot a function on a certain plane

Tags: plotting

I think that the general way of asking the question is the following: how can I ask Mathematica to plot a function on a certain plane?

A simple example.

Let's assume a function that is given by 
$$\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
X &= X_0+X_1+X_2 \\
X_0 &= 3 \tau \\
X_1 &= \cos(3 \tau) \cos(3 \sigma)\\
X_2 &= \sin(3 \tau) \cos(3 \sigma)
\end{aligned}
\end{align}$$

How can I plot the function X in the $(X_1,X_2)$-plane?

Comment: The definition of `X` is unclear, seems to be a scalar.. Is a spacepoint defined as `{X0,X1,X2}` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann It is a scalar. And the space point is defined as having the coordinates you mentioned. The coordinates σ and τ are the result of the spacetime embedding.

Comment: `x0=3 tau=const`define  the planes you're looking for. Eliminating sigma, tau gives  `( X1/Cos[x0)^2+( X2/Sin[x0)^2==1` (ellipse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing the elliptic constraint ( X1/Cos[x0)^2+( X2/Sin[x0)^2==1 (see my comment) the parametric form of the planes x0==const is

```
x1=Cos[x0] Cos[t];
x2=Sin[x0] Sin[t];
p[t_, x0_] := Evaluate[ {x1, x2, x0 + x1 + x2}  ]
```

`ParametricPlot3D` gives the plot

```
ParametricPlot3D[p[t, 0.5], {t, 0, 2 Pi},AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2", "x"}]
```

[image]

you're looking for!

Comment: thanks for your comment and the answer.

Comment: You're welcome!